# Graphical Model Equivalent of Matrix Pseudoinverse

Tags: graphical-model

The may sound like a strange question but I was wondering if a Pseudoinverse of a matrix could be found using SVD whether there was a graphical modelling equivalent that could be used to estimate the inverse of a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

If $A = U \Sigma V^{*}$ then $A^{+} = V \Sigma^{+} U^{*}$ where

$\Sigma^{+}(i,i) = \frac{1}{\sigma(i)} $ when $\sigma(i) \neq 0$ and 0 everywhere else.

Comment: Is there a name for this so I can look it up as a reference?

Comment: is sigma the standard deviation?

Comment: $\sigma$ are the singular values of the original matrix. Look up Moore-Penros Pseudoinverse

Comment: I have been using the Moore-Penros Pseudoinverse. My question was asking whether a Bayesian method existed?